# MySQLi connection cannot be established, normal MySQL functions work?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm using a MySQL 5 server and want to connect over MySQLi.

If I connect using `mysql_connect`, all works fine, but with MySQLi I got the following message:

> Warning: mysqli::mysqli() [mysqli.mysqli]: (HY000/2005): Unknown MySQL server host 'localhost:/tmp/mysql5.sock' (1) in /XXX.php on line 129
>      Cannot connect to database.

On another server, MySQLi works without any problems. Any ideas?

Comment: It's a shame there's a 15 character limit on comments. I only meant to write one word: "Code?"

Comment: Yes, please!  Show us the exact code that you use (with censored passwords, o'course) for both cases.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, you can see the class here : http://svn.contentlion.org/filedetails.php?repname=contentlion-core&path=%2Fsystem%2Fclasses%2Fmysql.php If you remove the @, you got the message.

Answer (score 1):

Try **localhost:3306** instead of Unix socket ?

Comment: It isnot possible, becauseof the settings from the provider

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution over Facebook!

I have to set ini_set('mysqli.default_so​cket', '/tmp/mysql5.sock'); and use just localhost as host.

Thanks anyway!